# Selection Sort Gone Wrong

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, selection

I am trying to do a selection sort using a comparable on an array. I am not sure why it is not working. If someone could take a look and help me find what is not working that would be great! Thank you!

```
public static Comparable[] no = new Comparable[100];

public static Comparable[] gen1()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int i=0;i<no.length;i++)
    {
        no[i] =random.nextInt();
    }
    return no;
}   

public static Comparable[] selectionSort (Comparable no[])
   {
      int min;
      Comparable temp;

      for (int index = 0; index < no.length-1; index++)
      {
         min = index;
         for (int scan = index+1; scan < no.length; scan++)
            if (no[scan].compareTo(no[min]) < 0)
               min = scan;
         temp = no[min];
         no[min] = no[index];
         no[index] = temp;
      }
      return no;
   }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Original Array:");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(gen1()));
    System.out.println("Sorted Array:");
    System.out.println(selectionSort(no));

}
```

Comment: I just tried out your code, and the sorting seems to work fine for me. I had to change the line that prints the sorted array to `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(selectionSort(no)));` Is this what wasn't working for you? If not, can you specify what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify what your problem is, but in the last line of main you should do

```
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(selectionSort(no)));
```

The output looks sorted to me.

Comment: Ah! Thank you!  It is always the most obvious things!